# Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, sql

Estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string.

Codigo PHP:

```
<?php

include("config.php");

 $query = $_GET['query']; 


    $min_length = 3;


    if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

        $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$query);

        $row_results = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM books
            WHERE (`Title` LIKE '%".$query.$conn."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query.$conn."%')") or die(mysqli_error());


        if(mysqli_num_rows($row_results) > 0){ 

            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($row_results)){

                echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['text']."</p>";

            }

        }
        else{ 
            echo "No results";
        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
    }
?>
```

Não entendo o que esta faltando

Comment: O que seria esses `$query.$conn` dentro da *query*?

Comment: o mysqli requer dois paramentros, neste caso o primeiro que é $conn é a conexão a base de dados e o segundo é SELECT statement

Comment: editei a resposta, agora tem o codigo todo

Comment: Sim, mas não faz sentido ter o objeto de conexão com o banco de dados no meio do `select`. Tente remover `$conn` onde está `$query.$conn`.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM books WHERE Title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR text LIKE '%".$query."%'"`

Comment: se retiro o $conn, da erro, diz mysqli necessita de 2 parametros

Comment: Qual `$conn` você tirou?

Comment: o que esta atras do SELECT

Comment: Veja meu comentário acima. Eu passei exatamente qual é o `$conn` que você deve retirar. Ele não deve estar DENTRO da instrução `SELECT`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58328/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-diana-madeira).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como amplamente discutido no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58328/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-diana-madeira), o erro está em utilizar o objeto `$conn` dentro da sua consulta, como destacado abaixo:

```
$row_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE (`Title` LIKE '%".$query.$conn."%') OR (`text` LIKE '%".$query.$conn."%')") or die(mysqli_error());
                                                                                       ^^^^^                                 ^^^^^
```

Não faz sentido você utilizar o objeto de conexão com o banco de dados dentro da consulta, portanto deve removê-lo. Outro erro que apareceu foi que você está tentando efetuar uma busca no banco de dados em uma coluna `text` que não existe, ou seja, deve remover esta parte do código também. Finalmente, outro erro no código é que você esqueceu de passar o objeto `$conn` como parâmetro da função `mysqli_error`, no final desta mesma linha.

Portanto, depois de corrigido, a linha deve ficar assim:

```
$row_results = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM books WHERE `Title` LIKE '%".$query."%'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```